# What is a good android disassember that can produce infomative results

Tags: java, android, disassembly

as titled, like function calls, application behavior when running

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few options.

"dexdump" is included with the SDK and is present on the device.  With the "-d" option it produces a no-frills disassembly of the methods.  The output format is intended to mimic the "--dump-to" output format of dx.

"smali/baksmali" is an assembler/disassembler for Dalvik bytecode.  It's [open source](http://code.google.com/p/smali/), and is probably the most complete solution.

"dedexer" is a disassembler that produces Jasmin-like output.  It's also [open source](http://dedexer.sourceforge.net/).

As far as I know, nobody has written a program that attempts to convert Dalvik bytecode to Java bytecode or source code.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried [dex2jar](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/) with 2 android market apps' APK and it works very well. If you combine it with jad, you can get the java source code.

See the [dex2jar's user guide](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/wiki/UserGuide) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The android development kit includes [a disassembler](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2009/01/disassembling-dex-files.html).  AFAIK, there are no to .class or to .java decompilers available at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a tool to convert dalvik bytecode to java one: [dex2jar](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/) . For now it crashes on most real applications, but could convert simple apps properly, so after using dex2jar & jd combo we get really good Java code. Also dex2jar is rapidly developing, it supports more and more cases.

Answer (score 0):

just as Frederic mentioned [dex2jar](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/) is so great, you can use dex2jar and jad to get readable *Java* source code instead of assembly-language-like "*.ddx" or "*.smail" file!