# Android dex to convert to java class format

Tags: java, android, dex

Is there any tool available to convert android dex file format to java class format?
I've looked at dex2jar, but it looked very early in development. I'd like something that is stable enought for use.

Comment: Some asm/disasm were listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505921/what-is-a-good-android-disassember-that-can-produce-infomative-results .  Don't know of anything that reliably converts back to .class.

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1249973/196561