# Disassembling Android app

Tags: android, obfuscation, deobfuscation

It turns out that Google [recommends](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/09/securing-android-lvl-applications.html) obfuscating your Android app.

In order to understand the problem, I would like to disassemble my own app and see what information I can extract from the code. How do I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a good android disassember that can produce infomative results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505921/what-is-a-good-android-disassember-that-can-produce-infomative-results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some tools are listed at [What is a good android disassember that can produce infomative results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505921/what-is-a-good-android-disassember-that-can-produce-infomative-results)

Also you can try undx http://undx.sourceforge.net/

Use them only for good :)

Comment: Thanks. Voted to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

There are [tools](http://code.google.com/p/smali/) [available](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) for that, such as the pair linked to in this sentence. I have not used them and therefore cannot vouch for how well or easily they work.